# Update resizable width in tablesorter

Tags: jquery, css, plugins, tablesorter, resizable

Having a problem when setting the resizable_width of tablesorter. I want to programmatically update the width of column of tablesorter with resizable widget.
I used

```
$("#tableId")[0].config.widgetOptions.resizable_widths = [
        '20%', '10%', '10%', '70%'
];

$("#tableId").trigger("updateAll");
```

But resize functionality is removed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As I shared in [the opened issue](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/1253):

> I've had issues with the resize widget not working well after an "updateAll". Is there a reason why "updateAll" is being used? To update the widget, you only need to trigger [`applyWidgets`](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#applywidgets) on the table.
>
> ```
> $("#tableId")[0].config.widgetOptions.resizable_widths = [ '20%', '10%', '10%', '70%' ];
> $("#tableId").trigger("applyWidgets");
> ```